# Add Label to WMS layer Using Mapbox GL JS

Tags: wms, mapbox-gl-js

[image: actullay this is a image without label and this layer have labels assigned at geoserver just i want that access those label and show them above layer so it can be rotatable]When We add wms layer to map Using mapbox gl js to vector map multiple layer get called and multiple time wms layer url called thats why we get many wms layer so if we have label with wms layer  when we zoom in we get multiple label of layer. so, i want to add same label externally and allow them rotate and all features of label in mapbox gl js.

```
map1.addSource('wms-test-source', {
'type': 'raster',
'tiles': 'url',
'tileSize': 256
});

map1.addLayer(
{
'id': 'wms-test-layer',
'type': 'raster',
'source': 'wms-test-source',
'paint': {}
}
);
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the problem to make your question clearer?

Comment: i want to add label to a layer when layer have label at geoserver end but i want that to be rotatable just like other mapbox label

Comment: All the other labels rotate because it's client side rendering. For the same behaviour, move the logic for labels to the client side. So, make your Geoserver send Vector tiles of labels and consume them.

Comment: To make single WMS calls to manage labels instead of the default WMS source, look at this demo https://gist.githack.com/ThomasG77/0feccc76e01bdbfd98b7f628c1c4e6f0/raw/def838975465efcf45884af95960cad3185c343d/mapbox-gl-js-wms-single-call.html
Trade off to not care about vector tiles but display labels once (not one time per tiles like with wms source) Be aware it solves the labels repetition issue not the labels rotation.

Comment: @ThomasG77 you have any idea how i can make my geoserver send vector tiles of labels and consume them.